# Countdown Timer in J2EE

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am working on an `Online Examination` project in `J2EE` and I want to put a `countdown timer` which allows a user to see the Time remaining before the exam gets submitted..
What is the most efficient way implementing this?
I have found one that using `Javascript` I can make one.
But, are there any API available in `JAVA` for these??? Moreover are there any other methods?

The data I have right now for `Countdown timer` is the `time interval` or the starting time which should be decremented to 0.

```
int time
```

Comment: If it is a web application then for sure you have to use java script

Comment: I am looking for a javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most efficient way implementing this?

Use JQuery `ajax` with `setInterval`. No server side timer is not needed to display count-down. Have a look at following sample example.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var time=100;
            setInterval(updateActiveStatus, 1000);

            function updateActiveStatus() {
                console.log('Count down call');
                time=time-1;
                if(time==0){
                 // Lock the exam by hide or display none.
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Servlet", // Call Servlet if any server side update needed.
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                        $('#countdownDiv').html(time);

                    }
                });
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/basic-coupon-site.html) jquery timer plugin. I've implemented it in my app. Works great.